# Does anyone have an actual example for how to use PUSHSTREAM and POPSTREAM?

Tags: antlr4

I want to be able to include ("import") source files but I don't need to do any preprocessing on them (not C or C++, etc). The only thing I need to be able to do is, if there's a syntax/semantic error in one of the included files, my error message would need to indicate in which file the error occurred.
From what I have surmised from reading, all I need is to use PUSHSTREAM in the lexer section but it's unclear to me exactly what I need to define. Would appreciate any pointers

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this at the lexer level? Do you need to support constructs like the "halfcondition.c" example in the article you linked?

Comment: Hmm, didn't think I had linked to anything - not sure what halfcondition.c is. Basically, all I want to do is combine all the files together and parse them as a single master source file but  if syntax/semantic errors are found, then I need to be able to say in which file (and line number, etc) the error occurred. So those other files simply become part of the sequence of tokens seen by the parser, which is why I assumed the lexer was the right place to do this. It's certainly the way I've done it in the past when doing such things by hand.

Comment: Sorry about that. I confused myself into thinking that you've linked [this article](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2686987/How+do+I+implement+include+files). My question was whether you need the ability to use an include statement in the middle of an expression (like the example in the article: `if (`, newline, `#include "somefile"`, newline, `i > 0)` where the included file contains `i < N &&`). If you work at the level of token streams, this will work, of course. But in most languages you don't need or want that.

Comment: Most languages that don't have a C-style preprocessing phase, that is.

Comment: Basically, at the top of my source files, I want to allow one or more "statements" of the form  IMPORT foo;  IMPORT bar; and so forth. Of course foo and bar might also have such statements at the top so nesting is required. I suspect I can do this quite easily with PUSHSTREAM but I just can't figure out the syntax I need to use.

Comment: If that's all you need and you don't need to support include statements in the middle of other statements like in the example I mentioned, you can do it quite easily *without* `PUSHSTREAM`. In fact, if you don't want to support that kind of syntax, you *shouldn't* use `PUSHSTREAM`. Just run the parser on the given file when you visit an include statement.

Comment: OK - maybe I'm missing something -- how do I CHANGE the source of lexical input from inside the parser -- I'm using the visitor pattern and by the time I see anything, the parse tree has already been created from the initial source and I'm generating machine code.

Comment: "how do I CHANGE the source of lexical input from inside the parser" I'm saying you don't need to (unless you want to implement C-like preprocessor mechanics, which I don't think you do). "I'm using the visitor pattern and by the time I see anything, the parse tree has already been created from the initial source" Yeah, but there's nothing stopping you from creating another parse tree from another source. Like `void MyVisitor::visitInclude(IncludeContext* ctx) { visit(lexAndParse(ctx->filename->getText())); }` (this leaks memory and might have other errors, but I hope you get the idea anyway).

Comment: `lexAndParse` is supposed to be a wrapper method that creates a stream that reads from the given file name and then invokes the lexer and parser on that stream. All that code didn't fit in the comment, but I hope the idea is clear anyway.

Comment: Hmm, that just seems wrong --- separate parse trees might make sense if one was handling separately compiled modules, for example, but not clear that's the right approach when you're just essentially wanting to pull all referenced files into a single large source file.  Where is 'lexAndParse' defined? I can't find that method in the source that I have.

Comment: Separate parse trees are the right choice if you want each of the files to be syntactically valid on its own. Modifying the lexer stream is the right choice if you want something like `if ( include "somefile" x < N)` to work where "somefile" contains `x >= 0 &&`. That's why I was asking about that example. If you don't need or want that to work (which I assume you don't), separate parse trees are definitely the right choice. "Where is 'lexAndParse' defined?" As I said, I've used that because I couldn't fit all the code in the comment. I hope it's clear anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry --- still having trouble with this stuff (had to defer for a few months and now getting back to it). The files aren't necessarily going to be syntactically valid by themselves so I am going to have to do this with the lexer. So I'm back to asking my original question. Does anyone have an example of how to use PUSHSTREAM?